# ng-options of object, how to get key value to function (angularJS)

Tags: angularjs, select, ng-options

```
//.js
    $scope.scopeObject = {
      "a":{},
      "b":{},
      "c":{}.......
    }
//html
    <div>
    <select ng-model="scopeModal" ng-options="key for (key,value) in scopeObject" ng-change = "getKey(group)"></select>
    </div>
//js
$scope.getKey = function(group){
 console.log(group)//undefined
}
```

In this case group is undefined in function...
How do i get value of key to my function? ty

Comment: What is `group` in your case?

Comment: <select ng-model="scopeModal" ng-options="key for (key,value) in scopeObject" ng-change = "getKey(key)"></select>*

Answer (score 0):

You should pass scopeModal to your function in change event. You can take a look at the following snippet.

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.scopeObject = {
      "a": {id: "a", value: "a"},
      "b": {id: "b", value: "b"},
      "c": {id: "c", value: "c"}
    }
    $scope.getKey = function(group) {
      console.log(group) //undefined
    }
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <select ng-model="scopeModal" ng-options="key for (key,value) in scopeObject" ng-change="getKey(scopeModal)"></select>
  {{scopeModal}}
</div>
```